# Unable to update WordPress or install plugins/themes

Tags: directory, ssh

I can't update WordPress from the back-end or install themes or plugins. Each time I try, I got this type of error: `Unable to locate WordPress Root directory.`.

I've installed my WordPress in a sub-directory. I have `/conclave` folder for WordPress files and `/content` for themes, plugins and uploads. My WordPress works fine, I can write posts, pages, and upload medias.

To allow me to update WordPress from the back-end, I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu). I'm quite lost about what to do and what's going on. I've check multiple things on the internet without success. Can you tell me what's going on ?

Here is the part of my `wp-config.php` file about the custom paths

```
/**
 * Set custom paths
 *
 * These are required because wordpress is installed in a subdirectory.
 */
if (!defined('WP_SITEURL')) {
  define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/conclave');
}
if (!defined('WP_HOME')) {
  define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '');
}
if (!defined('WP_CONTENT_DIR')) {
  define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/content');
}
if (!defined('WP_CONTENT_URL')) {
  define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/content');
}

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/conclave');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen when WP doesn't like the file owner. Can you change it to `www-data` and check file permissions? https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Or it could be that WordPress is getting confused by your `/content` folder, which is normally `/wp-content`. Have you defined `WP_CONTENT_URL` in `wp-config.php`? http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/renaming-wordpress-wp-content-folder/

Comment: Hey, thanks, it worked. But I don't really understand why. The Wordpress folder belonged to www-data group and www-data group has right to write and execute files in the Wordpress folder. So why didn't it worked ? Do you know this ?

Comment: Glad it helped! Themes and plugins live inside the wp-content folder, so if you have renamed that folder, you have to explicitly tell WordPress where to put those themes or plugins - otherwise it will try to install them to the default wp-content folder, which isn't there.